# Node js mongoose querying by dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to find out how to do an specific query with mongoose. I have in mongodb something like this:

```
 "startDateTime" : ISODate("2017-03-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
 "endDateTime" : ISODate("2017-03-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
```

I want to get all the documents which that specific date is within that `"startDateTime"` and `"endDateTime"`.
I have tried as follows but it returns no results.

```
     var criteria = {}; 
     criteria.$and = [];
     criteria.$and.push({ startDateTime: {$gte: queryDate} });
     criteria.$and.push({ endDateTime: {$lte: queryDate} });
```

Comment: your query seem correct. please check your `queryDate` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `queryDate` is Same for both of the conditions 
if your `queryDate` = `17-02-2016` you are searching for the records greater then that timeperiod and as well as lesser then that time period.

which is returning `[]` null because their are no records of this timeperiod

```
 criteria.$and.push({ startDateTime: {$gte: '17-02-2016'} });
 criteria.$and.push({ endDateTime: {$lte: '17-02-2016'} });

 var criteria = {}; 
 criteria.$and = [];
 criteria.$and.push({ startDateTime: {$gte: queryDate} });
 criteria.$and.push({ endDateTime: {$lte: queryDate} });
```